# How to stop ringing sound on incoming call in Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I want to stop the ringing sound when anyone call on my twilio number or is there any way I can make the incoming call to get retrieved automatically,I mean when any call comes to my twilio number it just instantly get received.I don't the caller to hear the ringing sound.

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As far as I'm aware, the ringing is the least possible, but it is also not under our control. As you can imagine, when you dial a Twilio number the call has to go through several networks before it reaches Twilio, Twilio then has to [make an HTTP request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request) to your application, retrieve the [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/) required to answer the phone and then respond to the call. All of that can't happen instantly so the phone will ring.

Does that make sense?